# Using CONCAT() + JOIN as display field in CakePHP Model

Tags: sql, cakephp, model

I have three models: Country, Language, and Market. A Market consists of a Country and a Language. There is no text field in the markets table, therefore no display field. Markets would primarily be used as a  option.

When doing $this->Market->find('list') from my controller, I would like it to say the country name and language name. Hence, I would like to do something like: CONCAT(Country.name, ' - ', Language.name), but I don't think that is possible, considering the 'list' SQL is simple, without joins.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet in this case is to do one of the following:

Setup your manual joins, and the Set::extract the results into a find( 'list' ) format.

Setup a mysql view, then use the standard find( 'list' ) on the mysql view as if it was a normal model representing a single table.